# Getting the most recent entry per group in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables to join to get table1.code, table1.series, table2.entry_date, table3.title1
and I'm trying to get the most recent non null table3.title1 grouped by table1.code and table1.series.

```
select table1.code, table1.series, max(table2.entry_date), table3.Title1 
                from table3 INNER JOIN table2 ON  table3.ID = table2.ID
                INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.source_code = table1.code
                where table3.Title1 is not NULL 
                group by table1.code, table1.series, table3.Title1
```

seems to give me all entries with a non null title1 instead of the most recent one. How should I structure the query to just pick the newest version of Title1 per code & series?

Comment: could you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select table1.code, table1.series, max(table2.entry_date), max(table3.Title1) as Title1
from table3 
INNER JOIN table2 ON  table3.ID = table2.ID
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.source_code = table1.code
where table3.Title1 is not NULL 
And Table2.entry_Date = (Select Max(sq.entry_Date)
                        From sq.table2
                        Where sq.id = table2.ID)
group by table1.code, table1.series
```

Comment: That gives the most recent date but not the corresponding most recent title added.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the order of tables; so Select from table1 and then join on to table2 & table3.  Are you able to post some DDL and sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this to join on only the most recent of the table2 entries?

```
SELECT
    table1.code,
    table1.series,
    table2.entry_date,
    table3.Title1
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2
ON
    table2.source_code = table1.code
AND
    table2.entry_date =
(
    SELECT
        MAX(maxtable2.entry_date)
    FROM    
        table2 maxtable2
    WHERE
        maxtable2.source_code = table2.source_code
)
INNER JOIN
    table3
ON
    table3.ID = table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with tlb as
(
    select table1.code, table1.series, table2.entry_date, table3.Title1,
    row_number() over(code, series, entry_date order by code, series, entry_date desc) as rn
    from table3 INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.ID = table2.ID 
    INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.source_code = table1.code 
    where table3.Title1 is not NULL
)
select * from tlb where rn = 1
```

This can be very quick depending on your indexes.